# How to print weight without pressing the button on Mettler Toledo scales

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

This is my code when I press button on the scale:

```
Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(sender As Object, e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived
    If comOpen Then
        Try
            readBuffer = SerialPort1.ReadExisting()
            Me.Invoke(New EventHandler(AddressOf DoUpdate))
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("read " & ex.Message)
        End Try
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub DoUpdate(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    TxtIn.AppendText(readBuffer)
End Sub
```

and my scales are [Metller Toledo AB204-S](http://www.mt.com/ch/en/home/phased_out_products/Laboratory_Weighing_Solutions/Analytical/AB-S/AB204-S.html).

Comment: If *you* don't tell it when to print the weight, how does the program know when to print the weight? Note that "print" usually means print the value onto paper. Perhaps you mean get the current weight value from the balance, in which case you would need to refer to the [MT-SICS Standard Interface Command Set - Reference manual](http://www.mt.com/ch/en/home/library/operating-instructions/laboratory-weighing/PL-S_SICS.html) - perhaps the "S" command is what you want.

Comment: Means having to press the print button on the scales, and without pressing the button on the scales can not?


thx for response sir

Comment: Have you tried sending commands from the PC to the balance and then reading the response from the balance? I think that is what you want to do.

Comment: already, i use code `serialport1.write("S" & vbCrLf )` like that?

Comment: Yes, something like that. You might be able to test it with Hyperterminal (or an equivalent if your computer is running Window 7 or later). Oh - I think that you have to use the correct serial port on the back of the balance - one of them is only for a printer and the other one is for printer and/or PC.

Comment: I've used it, but have not worked, btw how to use hyperterminal with send ascii code?

Comment: If you search on, say, Google, for "mettler toledo vb.net" you will find useful information.

Comment: Have a look at section 6.2 on page 36 of the operating manual linked here.  Check out the commands `Si` and `SIR`. http://www.mt.com/dam/mt_ext_files/Editorial/Generic/8/AB-S-FACT_PB-S-FACT_Operating_instructions_Editorial-Generic_1109912177440_files/ab-s-pb-s-fact-ba-e-11780762c.pdf

Comment: thank sir for ur response @DavidWilson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found my stuck

```
Private Sub BtnSend_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnSend.Click
    SerialPort1.WriteLine("SI" & vbCrLf)
End Sub
```

that's code command SI and CrLf